# Getting all input paths from MultipleInputs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

One of my mapreduce jobs is using MultipleInputs. After the job is done I want to remove input files. Unfortunately MultipleInputs has a very limited API and doesn't provide features as FileInputFormat `FileInputFormat.getInputPaths()`.

I looked into Hadoop's source code and it looks like I should be able to get all paths form `mapreduce.input.multipleinputs.dir.formats` but this is always empty for me.

Of course I can store all input paths somewhere "on a side" but I'm sure there must be a way to get it from Hadoops API.

```
    for(Path path : getParsedSitesToMerge(conf, crawlPath)) {
                MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, path, SequenceFileInputFormat.class, InjectLinkMapper.class);
                System.out.println(path.toString());
                System.out.println(MultipleInputs.DIR_FORMATS + ": " + conf.get(MultipleInputs.DIR_FORMATS));
}
```

outputs

```
file:/tmp/crawl1/link_db/links/parsed_1420300287148
mapreduce.input.multipleinputs.dir.formats: null
file:/tmp/crawl1/link_db/links/parsed_1420300308993
mapreduce.input.multipleinputs.dir.formats: null
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/MultipleInputs.html) part of code of MultipleInputs:

```
 public static final String DIR_FORMATS = "mapreduce.input.multipleinputs.dir.formats";
 public static void addInputPath(Job job, Path path,
 Class<? extends InputFormat> inputFormatClass) {
      String inputFormatMapping = path.toString() + ";" + inputFormatClass.getName();
      Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();
      String inputFormats = conf.get(DIR_FORMATS);
      conf.set(DIR_FORMATS,
           inputFormats == null ? inputFormatMapping : inputFormats + ","
           + inputFormatMapping);
      job.setInputFormatClass(DelegatingInputFormat.class);
 }
```

You could figure out using `String mappers = conf.get("mapreduce.input.multipleinputs.dir.formats");` to get all the paths which in from above code gets added whenever you say addInputPath from your driver code.

Comment: That's null for me as well. Btw is "mapred." not suggesting Haddoop 1?

Comment: Yes it is. Edited the same and Even i see the same `mapreduce.input.multipleinputs.dir.formats` in Gen2 as you. So how and where exactly you are trying to access this parameter?

Comment: `conf.get("mapreduce.input.multipleinputs.dir.formats") ` where conf is a reference to the `Configuration`. I'm also running it from Netbeans.

Comment: And you are trying to access it within map/reduce or somewhere else?

Comment: no I run it locally. I'm accessing config from driver.